# js list path info of object

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

Im trying to mirror how an S3 bucket works, and im struggling with the UI. So I have a bunch of json as follows

```
{"name":"sams file", "path":"testfile1.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder1/testfile2.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder1/testfile3.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/testfile4.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/testfile5.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/folder3/testfile6.jpg"},
```

Now i am looking to pass say lodash a value ie folder2, and im wanting it to return all file names in that folder and any folders it contains (not files) so i can build a UI, so im basically looking for an an array of

```
testfile4.jpg, testfile5.jpg and folder3
```

I should then be able to check if the item is a file or a folder and present the ui to the user

Does this sound possible, would anyone suggest an easier way to achieve what i want?

Thanks Sam

Comment: Your question will get a better response if you show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are trying to solve. As it stands, your question is too broad. There are many ways to implement this general functionality. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: Appologies, yes i should have posted my example, the answer by Nina Scholz is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the path, if it starts with the given string and then map the first coming folder or file.

```js
function getParts(array, string) {
    return array
        .filter(o => o.path.startsWith(string))
        .map(o => o.path.match(/\/([^\/]+)/)[1]);
}

var data = [{ name: "sams file", path: "testfile1.jpg" }, { name: "sams file", path: "folder1/testfile2.jpg" }, { name: "sams file", path: "folder1/testfile3.jpg" }, { name: "sams file", path: "folder2/testfile4.jpg" }, { name: "sams file", path: "folder2/testfile5.jpg" }, { name: "sams file", path: "folder2/folder3/testfile6.jpg" }];

console.log(getParts(data, 'folder2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the following way

```js
let arr = [
{"name":"sams file", "path":"testfile1.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder1/testfile2.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder1/testfile3.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/testfile4.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/testfile5.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/folder3/testfile6.jpg"}
];

let input_folder = 'folder2';

let result = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    a['files'] = a['files'] || [];
    a['folders'] = a['folders'] || [];
    let re = new RegExp(input_folder + '\/([^/]+)');
    let matches = b.path.match(re);
    if(matches != null){
        if(matches[1].match(/\./)){
            a['files'].push(matches[1]);
        }
        else {
            a['folders'].push(matches[1]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to filter the array to get all the items that contains this `folder` in their path, then `map` these results to keep only the file name.

You can use a combination of `.filter()` and `.map()` methods, like this:

```
    var results = files.filter(function(f){
       return f.path.indexOf("folder2")>-1;
    }).map(function(r){
        let reg = new RegExp('folder2\/([^\/]+)');
        let path = r.path.replace(reg, '$1');
        return path.lastIndexOf("/") > - 1 ? path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")) : path;
    });
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo:

```js
var files = [{"name":"sams file", "path":"testfile1.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder1/testfile2.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder1/testfile3.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/testfile4.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/testfile5.jpg"},
{"name":"sams file", "path":"folder2/folder3/testfile6.jpg"}];


function getFilesFolder(folder){
    return files.filter(function(f){
       return f.path.indexOf(folder) == 0;
    }).map(function(r){
        let reg = new RegExp(folder+'\/([^\/]+)');
        let path = r.path.replace(reg, '$1');
        return path.lastIndexOf("/") > - 1 ? path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")) : path;
    });
}

console.log(getFilesFolder("folder2"));
```